# Fancybox 2.1.3 Position within facebook custom tab

Tags: jquery, facebook, fancybox, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facybox 2.1.3 within a 1500px high facebook custom tab canvas.

I am unable to position the Fancybox popup in the center of the users visible screen.

I do not want to override the CSS with top:2px; etc as this means users at the bottom of the facebook canvas will have to scroll to the top.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

I am aware I can access the facebook outer canvas properties, but simply by knowledge isnt strong enough to work it out.

Regards

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/

Comment: Hi, That would make sense if I wanted the Facebook parent window to scroll to the position that Fancybox is in by default. Whereas I want Fancybox to position itself within the users visible screen. Also this doesnt work when you have a fluid height FB canvas which I do have and need. Appreciate the reference though.